# Checking that number is within an interval in Java

Tags: java, int, boolean, intervals

I have an input which represents an age. It can take values in the range 1..120. I must return a boolean to assess whether it is a correct age or not.

Input Arguments : int age
Result Type : boolean

Example Input Arguments : 25 0 120 121
Expected results : true  false  true  false

Example :
[image: example]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I am just learning

Comment: Show us what you've tried. We're willing to help, but we're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: Now I try to change your code for it though and true but clearly above the level of what we're going through at the rates :)

Comment: @АлександрСтариченко I think you can click on "reopen" below your question, to ask moderators to reopen it now that it's been edited

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isCorrectAge(int age) {
   return age > 0 && age <= 120;
}
```

#### General case :

```
private static int lowerBound = 1;
private static int higherBound = 120;

public static boolean isWithinInterval(int input) {
   return input >= lowerBound && input <= higherBound;
}
```

#### If you want to use the same function for different intervals :

```
public static boolean isWithinInterval(int input, int lowerBound, int higherBound) {
   return input >= lowerBound && input <= higherBound;
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution of all proposed.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] inputArray = new int[] { 25, 0, 120, 121 };
boolean[] resultArray = new boolean[4];
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    resultArray[i] = inputArray[i] > 0 && inputArray[i] < 121;
for (boolean result : resultArray) 
    System.out.println("" + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The validation of the age can be relative, and the most exactly you need it, the more complex in the algorithm will be,

so lets simplify this to only a natural number(i.e. an integer in java language),  so age must be positive and non zero:

then you need to define a function (i.e. a method in java language) that can return a true/false value (i.e. a boolean in java language) :)

```
boolean checkAge(int ageToTest){

    if(ageToTest > 0  && ageToTest < 120){
         return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

so easy is java language :)

Comment: You missed >120 part